# Filtering query by the field: recurrence/range/endDate

Tags: date, filter, calendar, microsoft-graph-api, odata

Is it possible (using Graph Api) to filter query by `recurrence/range/endDate` event field?
For other data types it works, but for the endDate field, which is a Date object, I get this error:

```
 {
       "error": {
         "code": "BadRequest",
         "message": "Invalid filter clause",
         "innerError": {
           "date": "2022-05-05T11:41:34",
           "request-id": "ed64dfc2-976b-4019-b518-ed3d5bf8aeb4",
           "client-request-id": "395dbcf6-0d91-4a66-b6bd-7e7457c261f0"
         }
       }
 }
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
 graphClient.users().byId(userId))
                 .events()
                 .buildRequest()
                 .select("subject,organizer,createdDateTime,start,end,recurrence")
                 .filter("recurrence/range/endDate ge '2022-05-05'")
                 .get();
```

Would anyone help?
Thanks!

Edit: 
I know about getting events from CalendarView but I would like to get them this way (i.a. not to include endDate in query).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out it's not possible to filter by Range becouse Recurrence property doesn't support filtering with Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: It looks like you can at least get the list of recurring by filtering on type as seriesMaster, then manually go through that list to build a sub-list of what you want to filter range values on.